# Proper use of aggregate statements in JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, criteria-api

I am struggling with the proper use of aggregate statements like `countDistinct`. I have found some examples for aggregate queries but none that is executed start-to-finish using `countDistinct`.

I have tried this:

```
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<MyClass> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyClass.class);

    final Root<MyClass> root = query.from(MyClass.class);

    final Predicate yearPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("year"), currentYear);
    query.select(root);
    query.where(yearPredicate);

    final Expression<Long> count = criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(root);
```

Here is where I am stuck. Is it correct to run `countDistinct` on the root? How do I get the result?   `query.select(count);` and `criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(query)` are both illegal. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope, this should help you:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Long> countCriteriaQuery = builder.createQuery( Long.class );
countCriteriaQuery.select( builder.countDistinct( countQuery.from( MyClass.class ) ) );

TypedQuery<Long> countQuery = entityManager.createQuery( countCriteriaQuery );
int totalObjectsNumber = countQuery.getSingleResult().longValue();
```

Comment: Aah, makes sense now :) Thanks, stemm